# Есть ли способ получить сслыку на ячейку памяти, где хранится объект?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет.

Мне интересны базовые вещи и то, как все устроено "под капотом".
Если я правильно понимаю принцип хранения данных в JS, то он следующий и поправьте меня, если я не прав:

Значения примитивных типов данных ( string, number ... ) хранятся в выделенной ячейке оперативной памяти. По этой же причине

```
"Some text" === "Some text" // true
```

Но значения ссылочных типов данных ( Function, Object, Array ) хранятся не в выделенной ячейке ОП, а в ссылке на эту ячейку. Ссылка - это некий адрес, который при каждом объявлении объекта, будет уникальным.
По этой причине `{} === {} // false`

А можно каким-то образом получить ссылку/адрес, в которой хранится объект? Т.е. физически как-то убедится в том, что существеут этот адрес? Или это только можно только низкоуровневым образом увидеть?

Comment: Ссылку физически получить из js нельзя. И строки не сравниваются по ссылке, а сравниваются по символьно.

Comment: Я не говорил, что строки сравниваются по ссылке)

Answer (score 1):

> Значения примитивных типов данных ( string, number ... ) хранятся в выделенной ячейке оперативной памяти. По этой же причине `"Some text" === "Some text" // true`

Равенство здесь истинно потому, что так работает оператор строгого сравнения со строками - сравнивает символы.

---

> Ссылка - это некий адрес, который при каждом объявлении объекта, будет уникальным. По этой причине `{} === {} // false`

Равенство здесь ложно потому, что так работает оператор строгого сравнения с объектами - сравнивает ссылки.

---

В частности вот тоже литералы примитивов и равенство ложно:

```
NaN === NaN // false
```

а тут для разных значений строгое равенство истинно:

```
-0 === 0 // true
```

---

> Но значения ссылочных типов данных ( Function, Object, Array ) хранятся не в выделенной ячейке ОП, а в ссылке на эту ячейку.

Ссылка - это адрес памяти, в ней объекты не хранятся.

Они тоже хранятся в памяти в виде определенной структуры. Но на них делается ссылка.

При копировании переменных копируется эта ссылка как примитивное значение, а объект не копируется.

Возможности получать ссылку в JS нет. Нет явного типа "ссылка". Как и применения такой ссылки, в отличие от других языков, где по ссылке можно получать какое-то значение.